# I set the rpath with gcc in MYSYS2 when compiling, but the program can't find it when running, so why?

Tags: c, gcc, dll, mingw, msys2

In my working directory there are *main.c* and a folder named *lib* with *libtest.dll* in it.

I use

> $ gcc main.c -ltest -L ./lib -Wl,-rpath=./lib

to compile, and the compilation process is no problem (no warning and error). But when i run a.exe the system remind

> D:/MYSY2/home/user/code/a.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libtest.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So why the library can be found when compiling but not when running?

Comment: Rpath is not a thing on Windows. The DLLs should be in the same directory, or in PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared libraries on Windows are `.dll` files and the are located by looking in the same folder as the running `.exe` file, or if that doesn't work by looking in the locations specified by the `PATH` environment variable.

So the best solution is to copy the `.dll` file(s) in the same location as the `.exe` file(s).

For distribution of your application you can use `copypedeps -r` from https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps to copy the .exe file along with any dependency `.dll` files, in case you are not certain which files are needed.